# ReactJS not clearing state after submission

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-state, react-typescript

I've been trying to add an item, and after Adding an item, I want to clear the state but it seems not working for me and I'm stuck.

Heres the button

```
<IonButton
  expand="full"
  color="primary"
  onClick={() => [AddNewTask(), setShowAlert1(true)]}
>
  Add Task
</IonButton>
```

AddNew Task function

```js
const AddNewTask = () => {
  const task: todoTypes = {
    id: v4(),
    title: newTask.title,
    content: newTask.content,
    color: newTask.color,
  };
  setNewTask({ ...initialNewTaskState });
  setTodoList([...todoList, task]);
};
```

State Declaration

```js
const initialNewTaskState: todoTypes = {
  id: "",
  title: "",
  content: "",
  color: "primary",
};
const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState<todoTypes[]>(todoData);
const [newTask, setNewTask] = useState<todoTypes>(initialNewTaskState);
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in console? This code should work, but you may have some errors that break your code.

Comment: Never start function name with a capital letter unless it is a functional component. Other than that code looks fine to me.